# Create Stored Procedure with Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure and I seem to be getting it wrong. I only use SQL when I need to, so please forgive a dev and help out. I want to include in the stored procedure a SQL query that does an inner join between two tables: user_students and student_grades_summary. Here is the stored procedure I wrote:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GradeStudents( in scoreover100 float, out s_grade char(3))
BEGIN 
CASE
        WHEN (student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 80 && student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 100 && student_grades_summary.level = 'JSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'A1';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 70 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 79 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'JSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'B1';
        WHEN (student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 60 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 69 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'JSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'B2';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 55 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 59 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'JSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'P1';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 50 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 54 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'JSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'P2';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 49 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'JSS')
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'F';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 85 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 100 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'A1';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 80 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 84 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'B2';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 75 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 79 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'B3';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 70 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 74 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'C4';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 65 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 69 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'C5';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 60 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 64 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'C6';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 55 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 59 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'D7';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate >= 50 AND student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 54 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'E8';
        WHEN(student_grades_summary.aggregate <= 49 AND student_grades_summary.level = 'SSS') THEN
            SET student_grades_summary.grade = 'F9';
END CASE;
```

And this is the SQL query that I am trying to include the stored procedure in. Basically I am trying to add values to the grade column in student_grades_summary by using the stored procedure. Anyways here is the sql:

```
select user_students.fname as FirstName, user_students.lname as LastName
     , student_grades_summary.subject as CoreSubjects
     , student_grades_summary.aggregate as Scoreover100
     , student_grades_summary.subjectrank as Position
     , student_grades_summary.term as Term
     , student_grades_summary.level as Level
     , student_grades_summary.class as Class
     , student_grades_summary.section as Section
     , student_grades_summary.session as Session
FROM student_grades_summary 
JOIN user_students 
   ON student_grades_summary.level = user_students.level 
   AND student_grades_summary.class = user_students.class 
   AND student_grades_summary.section = user_students.section 
JOIN config_grades 
   ON student_grades_summary.level = config_grades.level 
WHERE user_students.level = 'JSS' 
   AND user_students.class = '2' 
   AND student_grades_summary.session = '2015/2016'
```

So in phpmyadmin, I get a lot of red squiggly lines saying there is an error in SQL. I have tried to look at the code and find what the error is but haven't been able to.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set values in a table without using an update. The proc is not going to make sense of an arbitrary table name in a case statement. _Also, you don't/can't include stored procedures in queries._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this time and time again.  You are not thinking in SQL.  In SQL you need to think in sets. Don't think in sub-routines think in sets. In this case your set is a list of the criteria for a grade, which we can represent as a table (I'll call it grade_lookup)

```
aggmin aggmax lvl   grade
80       100  'JSS' 'A1'      
70       79   'JSS' 'B1'
60       69   'JSS' 'B2'
55       59   'JSS' 'P1'
50       54   'JSS' 'P2'
0        49   'JSS' 'F' 
85       100  'SSS' 'A1' 
80       84   'SSS' 'B2'
75       79   'SSS' 'B3'
70       74   'SSS' 'C4'
65       69   'SSS' 'C5'
60       64   'SSS' 'C6'
55       59   'SSS' 'D7'
50       54   'SSS' 'E8'
0        49   'SSS' 'F9'
```

Once you have the grade_lookup table you join to it and you get your grade -- no function call needed -- like this:

```
select user_students.fname as FirstName, user_students.lname as LastName
     , s.subject as CoreSubjects
     , s.aggregate as Scoreover100
     , s.subjectrank as Position
     , s.term as Term
     , s.level as Level
     , s.class as Class
     , s.section as Section
     , s.session as Session

     -- the result of our lookup
     , COALESCE(L.grade ,'lookup fail') as Grade

FROM student_grades_summary S
JOIN user_students 
   ON student_grades_summary.level = user_students.level 
   AND student_grades_summary.class = user_students.class 
   AND student_grades_summary.section = user_students.section 
JOIN config_grades 
   ON student_grades_summary.level = config_grades.level 

-- join to grade lookup
LEFT JOIN GRADE_LOOKUP L ON s.aggregate >= L.aggmin 
                   and s.aggregate <= L.aggmax 
                   and s.level = L.lvl

WHERE user_students.level = 'JSS' 
   AND user_students.class = '2' 
   AND student_grades_summary.session = '2015/2016'
```

> note, I just stuck this into your select statement -- I've no idea if your select statement is correct or not -- don't consider my re-using your example code as validation of it's correctness.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed explanation. I will look at this and let you know how this goes.

Comment: I will accept your response as the answer because it inspired be to look at everything and make the relevant corrections based on your response. thanks